get appx package is not recognized as a cmdlet
here's the error
PS C:\Users\Admin> Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallL
ocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
The term 'Get-AppXPackage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
 the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:16
+ Get-AppXPackage <<<<  -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\A
ppXManifest.xml"}
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AppXPackage:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

i tried it first when my windows key is broken
also i have NOT tried anything because i can't find anything that is about this
this is my first post so can't pose image:((
also my laptop is  k 55 a
windows 7 32 bit

Welcome to Superuser! Is Appx module installed? What version of Powershell are you using?

powershell 2.0... btw how do i fix broken windows keys ive tried everything on the microsoft help thingy

and its still broken

Try Install-Module Appx and then Import-Module Appx (from reddit.com). If it doesn't work, please provide the output from Get-Error after the failed command (from github.com).

I thought AppX was only in Windows 8 and later, not Windows 7.

@BenHutchison - It is, so running Get-AppXPackage, will do nothing on Windows 7. Get-AppXPackage does support the version of PowerShell the author is using and the version that does support it, cannot run on Windows 7.


i tried it first when my windows key is broken also i have NOT tried anything because i can't find anything that is about this this is my first post so can't pose image:(( also my laptop is k 55 a windows 7 32 bit

PowerShell 2.0 does not support Get-AppXPackage.  The command you are trying to run, does nothing on Windows 7, since Windows 7 does not have a Development Mode.
Due to the fact you are running Windows 7, there is no way to run Get-AppXPackage on your system, you would need to be running Windows 10+ with PowerShell 5.1 installed.  It's important to point out that the command you are running wouldn't fix any problems with the Windows key.
